# Ticket to Ride Europe: Drawing destination cards

Tags: ticket-to-ride-europe

I cannot find anywhere in the rules whether or not a player may hold NO destination cards. Is a player obliged to pick up new destination cards when he or she has run out? This is currently causing dispute in my household, so any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Destination tickets are kept secret until the end of the game and the final scores are counted. You can't start the game with no cards, and you can never discard the ones you keep, so there is no way to hold zero destination tickets at any point in the game.

This is written on the last page of the Ticket to Ride rules, the last paragraph under "drawing destination tickets".

> Destination Tickets are kept secret from other players until the Game's final scoring. A player may have any number of Destination Ticket cards during the game.

http://cdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_rules_en.pdf

Comment: That makes sense, we had been revealing destination cards as we went along!

Comment: You're also not required to pick up new destination cards when you complete your existing destinations.  It's perfectly legal to complete your first few destinations (or even ignore them, taking the penalty at the end of the game) and spend the rest of the game just buying long routes and/or blocking players.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer provided by Aether, the rules clearly state that a player must keep a minimum of two destination cards at the beginning of the game, out of the four that they are dealt.

> Before taking their first turn, players must choose which Destination Tickets they will keep from among those they were initially dealt. Each player must keep a minimum of two tickets although they may keep more.

The number of destination cards dealt is stated earlier:

> ... shuffle the long routes, and randomly deal one to each player. Put any remaining long routes back in the game box without letting anyone see them.
>
> Now shuffle the regular Destination Tickets - all short routes with a plain background -, deal three to each player, and place the remainder in a draw pile face down, next to the board.

By now each player should have 4 cards. Since destination cards cannot be discarded, it is not possible for anyone to remain without them at any point in the game.